# How to avoid exponential format for string which store double values from Database

Tags: string, forms, for-loop, exponential

I have a class like below from which is used to generating the XML using marshaller

I have a Database float column with 126 bytes which store big numeric values

For example: Salary FLOAT(126)

In class i have mappings like below

```
@NamedQuery(name = "example", query = "SELECT test FROM example test WHERE (test.xmlGenerate IS NULL OR NOT test.xmlGenerate = 'Y')")

public class Example {

@Column(name = "SALARY")    
private String monthlySalary;

}
```

Generated getters and setters for the salary in the class

Then I will be generating the xml using JAXB marshaller  using code below

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Example.getClass());
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(object, writer);
```

Now my problem is if the salary is having more than 8 digits it is getting generated to exponential form
Example: 110016400 to 1.100164E8
Please suggest on this how can I avoid exponential form because already I am using the string in place of double or long column so that it wont be converted to exponential form, even though it is getting converted to exponential form .Please suggest on this to avoid exponential form .

Comment: Can you change the type to `float`? `private float monthlySalary;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this
Retrieve the value from the DB as double, say

```
 public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
 }

 Convert it to String

 BigDecimal.valueOf(getSalary()).toPlainString();
```